# How do you initialize a Django FileField with multiple files?

Tags: django, file, widget

I have a model that saves multiple uploaded files for a document. I was able to use the `FileField` widget on the form to allow for multiple file uploads. However, whenever I went to update the document object, the `FileField` widget would not populate with the initial data. I was finally able to figure out that I needed to set the initial data and a URL on the initial data for the widget to render appropriately. But it just wasn't working out with a list of `File` objects. How can I get this to work right?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I had to write my own widget. I updated my requirements for the widget so that I only have to pass in a list of file objects so that the widget can render it however it wants.

**widgets.py**

```
class ClearableMultipleFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    """When setting the initial value of this widget, provide a list of the File instances."""
    template_name = "documents/clearable_multiple_file_input.html"

    def is_initial(self, value):
        return bool(value)
```

I needed to also create a template tag to process the file name of the file object. I didn't want to display the whole path; I was only interested in the file name.

**templatetags/document.py**

```
from pathlib import Path

from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(is_safe=False)
def file_name(value):
    return Path(value).name
```

And, finally, I had to re-do the template. I wanted to provide a link for each file in the passed in value. I did put in a condition such that if there were more than 25 files to just show the current file count. You can modify as you see fit. I should probably add an argument that you can pass into the widget, but I don't have the time right now. I copied the template file from Django and modified it appropriately.

**clearable_multiple_file_input.html**

```
{% load document %}
{% if widget.is_initial %}
    {{ widget.initial_text }}:<br>
    {% if widget.value|length <= 25 %}
        {% for f in widget.value %}
            <a href="{{ f.url }}">{{ f.name|file_name }}</a><br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {{ widget.value|length }} files<br>
    {% endif %}
    {% if not widget.required %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ widget.checkbox_name }}" id="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}"
           {% if widget.attrs.disabled %} disabled{% endif %}>
        <label for="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}">{{ widget.clear_checkbox_label }}</label>
    {% endif %}<br>
    {{ widget.input_text }}:
{% endif %}
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}" multiple{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
```

And to actually use the new widget:
**models.py**

```
class DocumentFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='files')
```

**forms.py**

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    extra_files = forms.FileField(required=False, widget=ClearableMultipleFileInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Document

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['extra_files'].initial = [f.file for f in self.instance.files.all()]
```

**views.py**

```
def file_exists_in_document(file, document):
    files = document.files.all()
    for f in files:
        if Path(f.file.name).name == file.name and f.file.size == file.size:
            return True
    return False


def delete_file_documents(document):
    for f in document.files.all():
        f.file.delete()
    document.files.all().delete()

class DocumentFormView(UpdateView):
    model = Document
    form_class = DocumentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        document = self.object.document
        # The cleaned data will return False if the "clear" checkbox is checked
        if form.cleaned_data.get('extra_files') is False:
            delete_file_documents(document)
        else:
            files = self.request.FILES.getlist(f"{self.get_prefix()}-extra_files")
            for f in files:
                if not file_exists_in_document(f, document):
                    DocumentFile.objects.create(file=f, document=document)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This could probably use some cleanup, but you gain a much greater understanding of the file widget. In future updates, you might want to have an individual checkbox for each file to clear from the file input widget. Since we are using only a handful of files, it isn't a great expense to ask the user to re-upload other files when they clear the widget.